# VS_VERSION_INFO Redefinition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I want to know if possible I can remove or hide this warning
I am using visual studio 2022 in my project. I don't know what's the cause of the warning.

> Blockquote 6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\verrsrc.h(18): warning RC4005: 'VS_VERSION_INFO' : redefinition

Comment: This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2022) contains methods for suppressing specific warnings.

Comment: Do not suppress this warning, it may fire back when you run your app.  Usually, after a line like this, the next line tells you where the culprit is. it is really hard to determine what is going on based on the description you have presented.
Search for all solution files for a VS_VERSION_INFO. it may also be defined in one of the dependencies.
Are you using any resource files in addition to your project's rc file?

Comment: Yes, I am using a Resource files aside from the Source.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try the following. Right-click on your project and select Properties. Go to C++ -> Advanced and change Show Includes as shown below:

[image]

This will show you all dependencies in order they are searched when the project is built. Search for verrsrc.h in the output window. You should be able to find a culprit. verrsrc.h should show in at least two places.

Comment: It is a warning generated by the resource compiler (rc.exe, note RC4005), not the C++ compiler.

Comment: Hans Passant thanks, I must have worn the wrong glasses.
@zetsu, sorry if I sent you on a wild goose chase. Could you please include a couple of lines surrounding the error message you are receiving?